# jwplayer 360p video takes to load

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

I have a problem with the plugin jwplayer
he has 2 medium 240p and 360p on my localhost it performs normally.
but when sending to hosting takes too long to load the video in 360p at 240p it loads faster, in fact I think he's waiting to load the whole video to play.

my code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("container").setup({
    height: "97%",
    width: "100%",
    primary: "flash",
    allowscriptaccess: "always",
    autostart:true,

  playlist: [{
      image: "uploads/snapshots/374f9c59b58f880c5e68762bde43318a.jpg",
    sources: [{
      file: "uploads/374f9c59b58f880c5e68762bde43318a.mp4",
      label: "360p"
    },{
      file: "uploads/374f9c59b58f880c5e68762bde43318a.flv",
      label: "240p"
    }]
  }],  
});
</script>
```

Comment: One thing to check is if your MP4 MOOV Atom is in the right place. Use this tool to confirm that and fix if needed - http://renaun.com/blog/2010/06/qtindexswapper-2/